# Cross Validation and bias relation

Tags: cross-validation

I found a question (Question 7) [here](https://www.sanfoundry.com/data-science-questions-answers-cross-validation/):

> Question: For k cross-validation, larger k value implies more bias
>
>  Options:  True or False

My answer is: **True**. 
**Reason:**
Larger K means more folds means smaller test set which means larger training set. As you increase training data you bring down variance which means increase bias.

So as K increases --> Training data size increases --> Variance reduces --> Bias increases
Hence answer is True

**But the website says answer is** **False**. 
Can someone explain if my logic is wrong and why their answer is right?

Comment: I'd take that quiz with a grain of salt anyway; at least 2, and 4's explanation, seem wrong.

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/61783/232706

Answer (score 1):

Why should bias increase as the training set size increases?

My intuition is that as you increase K, your test sets get smaller, increasing the variance of your evaluation metric. At the same time, you're fitting your model to more and more similar training data (since the training set in each fold is approaching the full set), so you're more likely to overfit to the training data because you're fitting your candidate models on almost the entire training data set in each fold.

Comment: I respect your opinion. But what I have learned from courses is that if you want to bring down variance (which will increase bias) you should increase training set size. I think this question is ambiguous. I think it depends a upon training set and model complexity also. If the model is very complicated like some deep learning model or may be even gradient boosting model it may start over fitting even if the fold size approaches entire data set, but if its some simple linear regression model then may be increasing fold size may not overfit.

Comment: I think it's important to remember that in this case, bias and variance are not always trading off. Generally, a good rule of thumb is that increasing the size of your training set with decrease both the bias and the variance of your models. So you can't just reason from "Well, increase the size of the training set so variance decreases so bias must increase" since that isn't necessarily true

Answer (score 0):

Larger K in cross validation means you have that many more Models created out of slices in your dataset. So - the average of the predictions from each of the K models - would even out the bias associated with outliers in your dataset.

Comment: Thanks for answering but in that quiz it was not clear whether the dataset have outliers. Practically I think we can assume that data set will have outliers.